# Why are my failed login attempts adding a banned IP but not banning me?

Tags: fail2ban

I'm failing some login attempts on purpose in a repeated fashion so as to trigger the banning of my IP address.

The `/var/log/fail2ban.log` file shows:

```
2021-05-29 14:27:34,332 fail2ban.filterpyinotif [154109]: DEBUG   Event queue size: 16
2021-05-29 14:27:34,332 fail2ban.filterpyinotif [154109]: DEBUG   <_RawEvent cookie=0 mask=0x2 name='' wd=2 >
2021-05-29 14:27:34,333 fail2ban.filter         [154109]: DEBUG   Processing line with time:1622302054.0 and ip:10.0.0.2
2021-05-29 14:27:34,333 fail2ban.filter         [154109]: INFO    [admin] Found 10.0.0.2 - 2021-05-29 15:27:34
2021-05-29 14:27:34,333 fail2ban.failmanager    [154109]: DEBUG   Total # of detected failures: 19. Current failures from 1 IPs (IP:count): 10.0.0.2:4
```

There was no banned IP before and there is now one:

```
example@vps:~$ sudo ufw status | grep REJECT
Anywhere                   REJECT      10.0.0.2
```

But the `whatismyip.com` website says my IP address is `90.190......`

And I can still access the website login page and do more login attempts.

My PHP application creates the log entry:

```
[29-May-2021 15:27:34 Europe/London] 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.example.com:80
```

The `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/admin.fail2ban.conf` configuration file:

```
[INCLUDES]

before = common.conf

[Definition]

failregex =  <HOST> - Failed admin login attempt for .* at .*
actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =
actionban = ufw insert 1 deny from <ip> to any port 80
actionunban = ufw delete deny from <ip> to any port 80
```

UPDATE: I changed the error logging so as to have the following date output:

```
2021-05-31 20:07:07+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:08+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:09+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:10+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:11+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:11+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:12+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
2021-05-31 20:07:13+0100 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.europasprak.com:80
```

using the function:

```
function reportWarning($message) {
  $dateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:sO");

  $errorLog = ini_get("error_log");

  file_put_contents($errorLog, $dateTime . " " . $message.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

The banning is working in fact:

```
2021-06-01 05:30:55,556 fail2ban.actions        [154109]: NOTICE  [learnintouch-admin] Ban 10.0.0.2
2021-06-01 05:30:55,561 fail2ban.observer       [154109]: DEBUG   [learnintouch-admin] Observer: ban found 10.0.0.2, 1800
2021-06-01 05:30:55,817 fail2ban.utils          [154109]: DEBUG   7fccfdb717b0 -- stdout: 'Rule inserted'
2021-06-01 05:30:55,818 fail2ban.utils          [154109]: DEBUG   7fccfdb717b0 -- returned successfully 0
2021-06-01 05:30:55,818 fail2ban.actions        [154109]: DEBUG   Banned 1 / 4, 1 ticket(s) in 'learnintouch-admin'
2
```

But on the wrong IP address.

```
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~$ sudo ufw status | grep REJECT
Anywhere                   REJECT      10.0.0.2
```

I did not put in place any reverse proxy. There is only a virtual host as in:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.europasprak.com
  ServerAlias www.europasprak.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/learnintouch/www/europasprak.com
  CustomLog logs/learnintouch-access_log combined
  <Directory "/usr/local/learnintouch/www/europasprak.com">
    Include /usr/local/learnintouch/engine/setup/url_rewrite.conf
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</VirtualHost>
```

All the HTTPD Apache proxy modules in the httpd.conf file are commented out.

Could it be that the OVH hosting provider has some kind or proxy in place ?

The HTTP service is deployed inside a Docker Swarm stack.

I reckon the issue I have is described [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25526).

UPDATE: I have installed the Traefik reverse proxy and can now see the public IP address of the client. The only thing left is to find out how to let Docker know a banned IP is to be banned.
Indeed the correct public IP of the client is banned but I can still access the website:

```
europasprak@vps-3506b083:~$ sudo ufw status | grep REJECT
Anywhere                   REJECT      99.99.99.99
```

Comment: Looks like you have *reverse* proxy and you log its address, not the real address of client which it hides. For discovering how to help that please describe your HTTP side software stack in detail, not only PHP.

Comment: Could it be that it's because the HTTP server is sitting inside a Docker container ?

Comment: It's a DockerSwarm issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25526 Now I need to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

> `[admin] Found 10.0.0.2`

This message shows that 1 failure is found. But it needs at least `maxretry` failures during `findtime` interval to cause a ban (and you'll see `[admin] Ban 10.0.0.2` notice in this case.

> But the whatismyip.com website says my IP address is 90.190......

Proxy?
Anyway you wrote that PHP application creates the log entry with `10.0.0.2`, so fail2ban has no chance to find your real IP, unless it is not logged.

> `[29-May-2021 15:27:34 Europe/London] 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt ...`

This is weird timestamp (use correct time-zone abbreviation like UTC or GMT instead of `Europe/London` by logging from your application), otherwise fail2ban would get a timezone issue here (default `datepattern` would not find match for `%z` here, so you'd get time deviation in fail2ban), as you see the 1 hour difference:

```
2021-05-29 14:27:34,333 ... [admin] Found ... 2021-05-29 15:27:34
```

Comment: I wrote this PHP application. I reckon the VPS is behind a proxy or something because the `_SERVER` variables are all empty except for one with this above IP address. I suppose I need to see with the hosting provider. The log entry is produced by the PHP method `error_log` but maybe I could change that date time format.

Comment: I also logged enough multiple retries so as to trigger the banning.

Comment: well, it may be that ufw reject rules does not really affect already established connections (see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/3018 for new action example killing the active connections)... but I wouldn't recommend to use this banning action (better is to use native net-filter instead).